# How to find a Particular value in particular range

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a example of the sheets, in which I am trying to create a macro with vba.

1. In the first sheet, there is a value for NAME in D3, which is 25, it can change but number only.
2. In second sheet, there is table. Where b1,b2, b3, b4 till b13, are name(variable) values from 1 to 13(As in sheet d3, different value). In A1 to a13, there is serial no. from 1 to 13.
3. In third sheet, there is table.
   Where b1,b2, b3, b4 till b13, are name(variale) values from 14 to 26(As in sheet d3, different value). In A1 to a13, there is serial no. from 1 to 13.

So, I want that the macro should check for sheet 1 d3 value in all worksheet, if found it will check for the serial no. against it, put the no. in E6 filed.

Comment: See this link http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: @user you can use `find-next` as above comment, then `vlookup` with some if conditions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143328/any-ideas-how-to-determine-what-age-group-an-individual-belongs-in-excel/14143756#14143756 - depending on the version you are using you can get lucky or a `regex` :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579466/i-need-macro-excel-code-which-will-check-if-my-string-is-in-the-correct-format/14580096#14580096 really you are better of with the earlier mentioned ones compared to the latter..

Comment: There are many platform where we can use VBA as a base for many programming and for macros. So, can you please tell me is this possible without vlookup I can do this kind of thing in VBA.. ??? –

Answer (score 1):

Sorry of I've misunderstood your question but it sounds like a vlookup might do the trick rather than the need to write VBA and use the Find method.

If you combine the second and third sheet, so that Column A contains the possible values for NAME in D3, and the Serial Number in Column B, like this.

```
NAME | Serial
-----|-------
1    | qwerty
2    | bob
...  | ...
```

You can then use a LOOKUP query as follows in E6.

```
=VLOOKUP($D$6,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While you're answer probably is right, I doubt that it really helps the inquirer! It's much better to provided a few more details, in this case for instance how to apply `VLOOKUP` in this situation...

Comment: Thanks, I must admit I was on my mobile at the time and being lazy, answer has been updated to provide more help (hopefully).

Comment: Sorry, I can do this in Vlookup. But I want the programming code in VBA. As I am not trying this formation only for Excel but for other vba programming software as well which use VBA language for macro.

Comment: So Please help me with VBA

Comment: I'm a little confused, most (if not all) VBA methods you'll use for this in Excel, will work in Excel only.  What other program are you using that this will for?

Comment: There are many platform where we can use VBA as a base for many programming and for macros. So, can you please tell me is this possible without vlookup I can do this kind of thing in VBA.. ???